# Unbiased estimator for $P(X_1=1)$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, estimation, inference

If $ X_1, ... ,X_n$ are IID binomial with parameters $  n$ and $p, $ find an unbiased 
estimator for

$$G(p)=P(X_1=1)=np(1-p)^{n-1}\, .$$

I need to find this estimator so I can apply Lehmann-Scheffé theorem. I think it can't be a "crazy" estimator. But I couldn't find anything. Can I have a hint?

$$\mathrm{E}[X_1(1-X_2/n)] = n p (1-p) \, .$$

Maybe it is a good way to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are IID $\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$, then for any bijection $\pi:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ we have
$$
  \mathrm{E}\!\left[X_{\pi(1)}\prod_{i=2}^n\left(1-\frac{X_{\pi(i)}}{n}\right)\right] = np(1-p)^{n-1} \, .
$$
Just pick one of these $n!$ unbiased estimators.